# Find a primitive to $\int \frac{\ln x}{x} x^{10} \:\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

While battling a bigger problem I encountered this integral that I cannot solve. Which techniques are useful in this (and similar) case(s), and what's the calculations to solve it?

$$\int \frac{\ln x}{x} x^{10} \:\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: put $u=\ln(x)$ and integrate by parts.

Answer (score 2):

If you take into account all answers and comments to your post, you could easily show that $$I_n=\int \ln (x)~ x^{n}~ dx=\frac{x^{n+1} }{(n+1)^2}((n+1) \log (x)-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:
$$\int x^n\,dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$
Simply differentiate both sides wrt $n$ to obtain a general formula.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{\ln x}{x} x^{10} dx = \int \ln(x) x^9dx$$

Integrate by parts now (｡◕‿◕｡)

$$\int u(x) v'(x) \, dx = u(x) v(x) - \int u'(x) v(x) \, dx $$

Answer (score 0):

First simplify the term inside the integral.
Then you can try a integration by parts integrating $x^9$ and derivativing $ln$ (you will need to know the boundaries).

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$F_{n} = \int x^{n} \ln(x)\,dx ,\quad n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Integrate by parts:

$$\int u(x)v'(x)~ dx = u(x)v(x) - \int v(x)u'(x)~dx.$$

Here 
$u(x) = \ln(x) \rightarrow u'(x) = 1/x$ 
$v'(x) = x^{n} \rightarrow v(x) = \frac{1}{n + 1}x^{n + 1}$

Thus, 
 
$$\eqalign{F_{n} &= \int x^{n} \ln(x)~dx = \frac{1}{n + 1}x^{n+1}\ln(x) - \int\frac{1}{n + 1}x^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} dx\\
F_{n} &= \frac{x^{n + 1}\ln(x)}{n + 1} - \frac{1}{n + 1} \int{x^{n}}dx\\
F_{n} &= \frac{x^{n + 1}\ln(x)}{n + 1} - \frac{1}{n + 1} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n + 1} + C\\
F_{n} &= x^{n+1}\left[\frac{ (n+1)\ln(x) - 1}{(n + 1)^{2}}\right]+C} .$$

Hope this helps,

Comment: You forgot the $x^{n+1}$ when you integrated $x^n$